# Account expiry dates or account Never expire for all AD users

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

While I am running the below command getting `expiration_date` is blank.

Is it possible to get the 'Never expire' instead of blank in `expiration_date`?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -filter {Name -like "SSL_VPN_Users" } | Select-Object Name
ForEach ($Group in $Groups) {
  Get-ADGroupMember -identity $($group.name) -recursive | 
    Get-ADUser -Properties samaccountname,mail,AccountExpires | 
    select samaccountname,mail,@{l="expiration_date";e={[datetime]::fromfiletime($_.accountexpires)}} | 
    Export-csv -path C:\SSLVPN\SSL_VPN_Users.csv -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: `Get-ADUser -Properties AccountExpirationDate`, not `AccountExpires`

Comment: Like you said I have changed it but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably when the account never expires the value of `AccountExpires` is the max. `int64` value which results in an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` when calling `[datetime]::FromFileTime` for it.

Therefore try the following - I introduced the helper function `accountExpiresToString` for better readability of the expression script block but you can pack the function's code directly within the script block if you prefer that.

```
function accountExpiresToString($accountExpires) {
    if (($_.AccountExpires -eq 0) -or 
        ($_.AccountExpires -eq [int64]::MaxValue)) {
        "Never expires"
    }
    else {
        [datetime]::fromfiletime($accountExpires)
    }
}

Import-Module ActiveDirectory
...
ForEach ($Group in $Groups) {
  Get-ADGroupMember ... | 
    Get-ADUser -Properties ...,AccountExpires | 
    Select-Object @{l="expiration_date";e={ accountExpiresToString($_.AccountExpires)}} | 
    Export-Csv ...
}
```

Update: If of interest, here is a [page on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675098(v=vs.85).aspx) describing that 0 and 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF (`[int64]::MaxValue`) indicates an account that never expires.

Comment: Thanks expiration_date is coming as "Never expires" But I still have "blanks"  instead of "never expires" for some users if I run my code its coming as "01.01.1601 02:00:00"  instead of  "blanks" for some users whats the issue?

Comment: It seems that both 0 and `[int64]::MaxValue` is used to indicate that an account never expires - see my update

Comment: when attempting to run I'm getting error like You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator. At line:2 char:27 Unexpected token 'in' in expression or statement.

Comment: I guess you are using an older version of PowerShell (2.0 I guess) - I updated the answer to replace the `-in` operator with an `-or`. Please try again

Comment: ok but I cant see  account expiry dates for some users its coming as blank field. if I run my code I can see account expiry dates because not setting never expires for some users

Comment: Well then please show their values in AccountExpires so that one is able to reproduce it

Comment: for example if I set the account expires to 06.08.2016 00:00:00 In AD the value is actually  131149044000000000   value   in Attribute editor

Comment: there was a typo in the expression script block (a missing 's' at the end of $_.AccountExpire) - did you fix that by yourself or did you copy it as well? bc from what I see it should work for the value 131149044000000000

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120964/discussion-between-arbelac-and-daxaholic).